# C++11 chrono in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, c++-chrono

I am porting a code from Linux to Window.

And There is a error i didn't expect in using std::chrono.

since std::chrono is C++ standard library, i expected that it is working without modification.

below is the code showing the error.

the error happen at the parts where i use operator with duration instances and duration_cast function `with no instance of function template`.

in Linux, the code works normally

```
std::string ChronoTimer::currentTime(){
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = system_clock::now();
    time_point<system_clock> epoch;

    microseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(now - epoch);

    hours hour = duration_cast<hours>((ms % hours(24)) + hours(9));
    minutes min = duration_cast<minutes>(ms % hours(1));
    seconds sec = duration_cast<seconds>(ms % minutes(1));
    milliseconds msec = duration_cast<milliseconds>(ms % seconds(1));


    std::stringstream strStream;
    strStream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << hour.count() << ":";
    strStream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << min.count() << ":";
    strStream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << sec.count() << ".";
    strStream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3)<< msec.count();
    return strStream.str();
}
```

[image]

```
1   IntelliSense: no instance of function template "std::chrono::duration_cast" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (<error-type>)  


2   IntelliSense: no operator "+" matches these operands
        operand types are: std::chrono::system_clock::rep + std::chrono::hours  

3   IntelliSense: no instance of function template "std::chrono::duration_cast" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (std::chrono::system_clock::rep)
```

Comment: How about showing us the **actual error message**? (And indicate the line where it occurs clearly in the code you posted)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: sorry i add the contents

Comment: Ignoring the intellisense errors (Which actually never works well and shows many errors even if the program is well-formed), that program compiles fine?

Comment: This is a visual studio bug that should be reported.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug:  operator% yields a long long whereas it should yield a duration like operator+ and operator- according to ISO in section 20.13.5.5 (duration non-member arithmetic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below I post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that focuses on your problem:

```
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {
  auto now = system_clock::now();
  time_point<system_clock> epoch;
  microseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(now - epoch);
  microseconds hs = std::chrono::hours(1);
  auto mm = ms % hs;
}
```

Although the above example works on [<kbd>GCCv4.9</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d5a87f68e7c29df) and [<kbd>CLANGv3.4</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8af757d7c4f33fae). It fails to compile in VS2013.

The error reports that VC++ can't convert `std::chrono::microseconds` to `std::chrono::system_clock::rep`.

It seems that the implementers are messing something with the conversions, I consider this is a visual C++ bug that should be [**reported**](https://connect.microsoft.com/).

Comment: [This bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/959253) has been resolved, and is in [VS2013 CTP Release 14.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp.aspx)

Comment: Do I need to upgrade the VS2019 to VS2023 or just an update will suffice?